# Multple DB connections in a single Java application

Tags: java

Is there any way to handle more than one DB connection in a single *Java* application or do I have to go towards *Web Services*?

Comment: Of course two Connections / DataSources / persistence managers are possible. Could you explain your intended usage?

Comment: How do you create a DB connection in your java application?

Comment: What @GerardH.Pille said, but just twice that.

Comment: You saw me coming, didn't you, @Stultuske ?

Comment: open goal and all that :)

Comment: @JoopEggen actually i want to to do something from my code on three different types of DB(Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Anywhere).

Comment: Then simply get 3 different connection variables: `Connection oraCon = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:...","...","..."); Connection mysqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql:...","...","..."); ...`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really simply: Yes.
If you use JDBC, just create multiple instances of `Connection` by means of `DriverManager.getConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create multiple connection by retrieving connection from connection-pool or just retrieve connection.

Eg -

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid","username","password");

    return con;
}
```

Calling getConnection() multiple times means you have multiple Connections, You can also have getProductionConnection(), getDevConnection() with respective configurations.

Comment: This can create multiple connection from a single DB but I want to create multiple connection from multiple databases.

Comment: That is also possible, just call getSomeDatabaseConnection(), and configure your url, username and password

Comment: A simple example with datasource - 
DataSource datasource1 = getLocalDbDataSource();
DataSource datasource2 = getAnotherDataSource();

Connection conn1 = datasource1.getConnection();
Connection conn2 = datasource2.getConnection();

DataSource is basically configured using JNDI or url, username, password combination